# pie chart DynamicHeight property causing huge white space issue in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, charts, whitespace, ssrs-2008

I can successfully get the dynamicheight property of a pie chart to match the size of a table it appears adjacent to in the report.

The problem is that by using this property, RS is now inserting huge amounts of white space beneath the pie chart.

Why is this occuring and how can I make it stop?

Comment: possible duplicate of [DynamicHeight pie chart underlapping other objects in the same rectangle in reporting services 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608189/dynamicheight-pie-chart-underlapping-other-objects-in-the-same-rectangle-in-repor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [DynamicHeight pie chart underlapping other objects in the same rectangle in reporting services 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608189/dynamicheight-pie-chart-underlapping-other-objects-in-the-same-rectangle-in-repor)