# DynamicHeight pie chart underlapping other objects in the same rectangle in reporting services 2008

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008

I have a pie chart in SSRS 2008 which when it reaches a certain size is underlapping objects which appear below, but still inside the same rectangle; the height of the pie chart is calculated using the DynamicHeight property of the chart

Apparantly:

> Using Rectangles to Control Item Growth and Displacement
>   Items within a rectangle become peers of each other and are governed by the rules of how peer items are positioned on the page as they move or grow. For example:
>   •
>   **Items will push or displace each other within the rectangle**.
>   •
>   Items will not push or displace items outside the rectangle, because they are not their peers.
>   •
>   **If necessary, a rectangle will grow to accommodate the items it contains**.

The words of Brian Welcker and Chris Hayes I might add.

Either they are wrong or there is a bug.
Anyone know of a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that despite the objects giving the illusion of being inside one of the many rectangles - it turns out they weren't.

Difficult to know given that I meticulously moved all of the objects outside to a clean area, created a new rectangle in the relevant spot, then dropped all the objects inside (or so I thought) the new rectangle.

If it hadn't been for the "Document Outline" tree view I would never have discovered this.

Frankly I find this behaviour pretty crappy - it should prompt you if you want to add the objects to the rectangle just to confirm.